# Handle Optional field search in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I am new to query for elasticsearch. I have the problem which took me so long to do research and implement it.
I have 4 fields for searching but not all fields has to be chosen when do searching, some field can leave blank.
For example, employee first name, employee last name, job title and department. I would perform searching such use case: just put first name and last name to get all people have that first and last name, or I can choose last name + first name + job title, or I can choose last name and department only and other params leave blank.
Anyone has an idea for the query. I would appreciate any suggestion.
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean that your users fill in which fields they would like to search?

Comment: yes, correct, they can choose all field or some fields @ShiraElitzur

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve your use case is to use bool query or query_string

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "department": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "fname": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "lname": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index data:**

```
{
  "fname": "john",
  "title": "faculty",
  "department": "navy"
}
{
  "fname": "smith",
  "title": "faculty",
  "department": "navy"
}
{
  "fname": "Will",
  "lname": "Smith",
  "title": "Student",
  "department": "engineering"
}
```

**Search Query using [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html):**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "fname": "Smith"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "faculty"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "department": "navy"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67550433",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.9208363,
        "_source": {
          "fname": "Smith",
          "title": "faculty",
          "department": "navy"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**OR you can even use [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)**

```
{
  "query":{
    "query_string":{
      "query":"fname:smith AND title:faculty AND department:navy"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Sam Luong please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: thanks for your response. but in the query, we won't know which field the user will choose for searching. for example, sometimes, use choose only first and last name to search and leave others fields blank, sometimes, u will chose last name and dept to search and leave other blank, sometimes, u can choose 3 fields, we won't know which field. I tried the bool query like u did before, but when I leave blank in the value (by empty string or null), it gave some error

Comment: all index data have all 4 fields, but in the search query, not all 4 fields are required all the time, which fields be chosen should perform AND operation

Answer (score 0):

You can build your query programmatically, as a key-value hash with a 'must' key, and by looping through your input field types, add your fields to the 'must' only if provided.
Alternatively, you can put all the fields under a 'should', assuming that no match will be found for the blank values and therefore there will be no impact on the score and results.